# Comfortable arm rest

Tags: comfort, furniture

I already brought a chair and the chair is doing well for my purposes. But, an issue is that is has fixed arm rests. For my height, I cannot able to keep my arms comfortably.

There is atleast 5 cm gap between my arms and the arm rest.

Is there any hack that makes me comfortable to keep my arms on?

Answer (score 5):

If you need to make the armrest higher, get a pool noodle. Cut to the right length and with a slit, you can slip it on the armrest. Alternatively, there’s pipe insulating foam available at your local hardware store - that already comes with that lengthwise slit.

Optional: Fixing the foam with zip ties or tape.
Even more optional: Add a decorative cover (fabric, (faux) leather...)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the arms or armrest are attached, you may be able to cut and insert a spacer such as a piece of wood at the attachment point.  There are also padded arm rest covers available which slip over the existing arm rest.  This can make the arm rest a good deal taller (and softer).  You can find them by searching your favorite online retailer for "arm rest pad".